# How to prevent dropdown from executing when source list is changed programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have an activeX dropdown form on my spreadsheet which executes code on `_Change`. My code modifies the dropdowns list source (adding or deleting items). Whenever this happens, the `_Change` is called again.

I have various workarounds, all of which were some version of changing the list source, but with no success. The reason none of this has worked is because clearing or altering the `.ListFillRange` actually triggers the `_Change` event again.

**How do I prevent the `_Change`event from getting called if I want to add or delete items in the `.ListFillRange`**

UPDATE w EnableEvents set to false:

```
Public Sub SetRangeForDropdown()
On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Get new List of employees from Employee sheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    With wsDB_employee
        Set rng1 = .Range("A2:B" & .Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    With wsStage
        .Cells.Clear
        rng1.Copy .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rng1.Rows.Count, 2))
    End With

    'Set range for dropdown on employee sheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = wsStage.Range("A1:B" & wsStage.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Update employee list named formula
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="nfEmployeeList", RefersTo:=rng2
    Dim str As String
    str = rng2.Parent.Name & "!" & rng2.Address 'Source path for list fill range
    wsMA.cmbEmployeeSelection.ListFillRange = str

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Apperantly **`EnableEvents` does not work for ActiveX controls**.

Thank you Microsoft for making life just a little bit more complicated!

Just found this: "Application.EnableEvents=False/True ONLY applies to Sheet and Workbook Events, not ActiveX Control Events" from here [enter link description here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56965)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding a global variable that prevents the `_Change` event from firing. Here is that code:

```
Private Sub cmbEmployeeSelection_Change()

If bNOTRUN = False Then 'Check if ActiveX event should fire or not

    modEmployeeDB.SaveEmployeeData 'Save currently selected employee data
    modEmployeeDB.DBSoll_To_WorkerInfo 'Get called employee data

End If

End Sub
```

And this is the module as modified... note the simple Boolean variable that I added:

```
Public Sub SetRangeForDropdown()

On Error GoTo SetRangeForDropdown_Error

    bNOTRUN = True 'Global Variable that when True prevents Active X from firing

    'Get new List of employees from Employee sheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    With wsDB_employee
        Set rng1 = .Range("A2:B" & .Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    With wsStage

        .Cells.Clear
        rng1.Copy .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rng1.Rows.Count, 2))

    End With

    'Set range for dropdown on employee sheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = wsStage.Range("A1:B" & wsStage.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Update employee list named formula
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="nfEmployeeList", RefersTo:=rng2
    Dim str As String
    str = rng2.Parent.Name & "!" & rng2.Address 'Source path for list fill range
    wsMA.cmbEmployeeSelection.ListFillRange = str

    bNOTRUN = False

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

SetRangeForDropdown_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure SetRangeForDropdown of Sub modEmployeeDB"
    bNOTRUN = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the events in the `SetRangeForDropdown` and then enable them back.

So, write the following at the start:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And the following at the end:

```
Application.EnableEvents = true
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you

Comment: sorry to be unchecking the answer... but despite having set `Application.EnableEvents = False` the `_Change` event get triggered again if I call it from another procedure. So unfortunately something else is still going on.

Comment: The code gets triggered again on the line with `.Cells.Clear`

Comment: Can you write before .Cells.Clear the following >Debug.print Application.EnableEvents< and check its status?

Comment: If you call it from another procedure, you should write the Application.enableEvents = FAlse and True in this procedure as well.

Comment: I added the Debug.Print and it comes up as "False"... so it should work, but somehow it still goes to the change event :- (. What I've noticed is that the event is triggered by both changing the `.ListFillRange` as well as the actual Destination Field... I had already tried implementing the `EnableEvents` on the calling level procedure. It also didn't help.

Comment: Are you debugging with F8? Step by step, thus being sure that it is exactly the .cells.clear that send you to the _Change? It can be that you get there somehow else.

Comment: I'm going through using F8. It is def the `.cells.clear` that calls the other event. I have even added the `Debug.Print` before the `_Change` code and it keeps on telling me that it is disabled (FALSE). Anytime the ActiveX Dropdown source is modified it calls the event. Very strange... I've never encountered this problem before. I'm beginning to think this is a bug.

Comment: Just found this: "Application.EnableEvents=False/True ONLY applies to Sheet and Workbook Events, not ActiveX Control Events" from here http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56965

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by adding a Boolean Variable. Crude and not really a satisfying solution, but it seems to be the one that everyone ends up with. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

it's always a good habit to make (nearly) sure that events handling is always brought back, like follows:

```
Public Sub SetRangeForDropdown()


'...your code

    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    wsMA.cmbEmployeeSelection.ListFillRange = rng2

    'Update employee list named formula
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:="nfEmployeeList", RefersTo:=rng2

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Furthermore, avoid `On Error Resume Next` unless you really need it

Comment: Saddly, this does not seem to have taken care of it yet. Thank you also for taking a look.

Comment: Implemented your recommendation and replaced the error handler

Comment: Without making any kind of advertisement, consider installing MZ-Tools for the automatic error handler writing. It would help you a lot.

Comment: I have MZ-Tools and I do in fact use it quite a bit... though i have found that the error handler code is usually not that helpful...